# What particular functions that can perform Ncurses scanw() and printw() in the Form library?

Tags: ncurses, curses

I have a simple Ncurses program that will ask for an ID number and the system will return for this ID number using scanw() and printw() functions respectively. Now, if I'm going to use the Form library #include <form.h> what functions should I use?

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int
main()
{
        initscr();
        char idnum[9];

        nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);
        printw("Enter ID number: ");
        refresh();
        scanw("%s", idnum);
        printw("The ID number entered is: %s\n", idnum);
        refresh();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Forms don't have a scanw.  You could create a temporary window over top of a field and accept input in that window, using the result to set the contents of a [field_buffer](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form_field_buffer.3x.html).

Comment: Thank you @ThomasDickey for answering my query! I will explore your recommendation.